# Ansible Enabling Postgresql Services

Tags: postgresql, ansible, yaml

I'm trying to enable these postgresql services with an ansible playbook, but I get this error all the time

```
TASK [postgresql : enabling postgresql services] ******************************************************************************************************
fatal: [some-remote-server]: FAILED! => {
"changed": false, 
"cmd": "'systemctl enable postgresql-9.6.service' 'systemctl start postgresql-9.6.service'", 
"rc": 2
}

MSG:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This would be my task

```
- name: enabling postgresql services
  check_mode: no
  command:
  args:
    argv:
      - systemctl enable postgresql-9.6.service
      - systemctl start postgresql-9.6.service
  become: yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use the [service](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_module.html) module

```yaml
    - name: enabling postgresql services
      service:
        name: postgresql
        state: started
        enabled: yes
```

Comment: This is the MSG I'm getting:
Service postgresql not found on host, assuming it will exist on full run

Comment: You're welcome. Name of the service depends on the system. Ubuntu(Debian) will tell you *service --status-all*. BSD systems list *service -l*. HTH.